# Guessing random number project

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a newbie of coding. I'm trying to create a guessing random number game by python. The thing is I get stuck at limited users by 5 turns guessing only. Here is my code so far. Thank you

```
print("""
WELCOME TO GUESSING NUMBER GAME!!!
You have 5 turns to guess a random number. Good luck!
""")

def play():
import random
random_numnber = random.randint(0, 20)
guess_count = 0
while True:
    try:
        guess = int(input("Please enter an integer from 1 to 20: "))
        guess_count += 1
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid Input\n")
        continue
    else:
        break

while random_numnber != guess and guess_count < 5:
    if int(guess) < random_numnber and int(guess_count) < 5:
        print("Your number is too low\n")
        guess = input("Enter an integer from 1 to 20: ")
    elif int(guess) > random_numnber and int(guess_count) < 5:
        print("Your number is too high\n")
        guess = input("Enter an integer from 1 to 20: ")
    elif int(guess) == random_numnber and int(guess_count) < 5:
        print("Congratulation! You Win!\n")
        break
    else:
        print("You have guessed 5 times and all Wrong. Good luck on next game!")
        break

while True:
answer = input("Do you want to play? ")
if answer == 'yes' or answer == 'y':
    play()
elif answer == 'no' or answer == 'n':
    break
else:
    print("I don't understand\n")
```

Comment: Can you explain what you expect it to be doing, that it is not? Also take a look at your indentation, it's much easier to help if we can copy and paste the code without having to guess how it should be formatted.

Comment: Yes Sir. The game is worked. But I would like to limit users have 5 turns to guessing the random number only. After 5 times if they don’t guess the right number. They lose.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would go about doing this, I have modified your code and omitted some trivial error handling for non-integer inputs, etc.

The trick is that the code section between the `# ***` comments will be exited automatically if the `guess_count` value exceeds the `maximum_tries`, so we can actually remove a lot of the conditionals you were performing in-line which cluttered the real logic we care about.

You can also see that the only way that we can reach the line where we print `"All out of guesses"` is if the user has not already guessed the correct number.

Finally, since you mentioned you are just starting out I included a `main()` function as well as the Pythonic block at the end, which is just a special way to tell Python which part of the program you want to *start with* when you run the script. Happy coding!

```py
def play():
    import random
    random_number = random.randint(0, 20)
    guess_count = 0
    maximum_tries = 5
    # ***
    while guess_count < maximum_tries:
        guess = int(input("Please enter an integer from 1 to 20: "))
        if guess == random_number:
            print("You win!")
            return
        elif guess < random_number:
            print("Too low")
        elif guess > random_number:
            print("Too high")
    guess_count += 1
    # ***
    print("All out of guesses")

def main():
    while True:
        answer = input("Do you want to play? (y/n): ")
        if answer.startswith('y'):
            play()
        elif answer.startswith('n'):
            print('Goodbye')
            break
        else:
            print('I don\'t understand')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Your code look much tidy than mine. However, somehow I believe you don't do anything with guess_count so it still not limit 5 turns. But I do figure out the solution. Thank you for awesome job. Happy coding!

Comment: How silly of me! I have added the missing line. If you're happy with this answer, go ahead and click "Accept" so that others know it worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
def play():
import random
random_number = random.randint(0, 20)
guess_count = 0
maximum_tries = 5
# ***
while guess_count < maximum_tries:
    guess = int(input("Please enter an integer from 1 to 20: "))
    if guess == random_number:
        print("You win!")
        return
    elif guess < random_number:
        print("Too low")
    elif guess > random_number:
        print("Too high")
guess_count += 1
# ***
print("All out of guesses")

def main():
while True:
    answer = input("Do you want to play? (y/n): ")
    if answer.startswith('y'):
        play()
    elif answer.startswith('n'):
        print('Goodbye')
        break
    else:
        print('I don\'t understand')

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```